# Navigation Title Chopped with external Font 'FuturaStd-Book'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationitem

[image: Navigation Item Title Chopped]

Title chopped in Navigation with external Font 'FuturaStd-Book'.

Tried to decreased Font size with following code but still title chopped.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FuturaStd-Book" size:16]}];
```

Kindly help me on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to use the `titleView` of the `navigationItem`. Try this in your VC:

```
    UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 44.0)];
    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.text = @"Register";
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FuturaStd-Book" size:16];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = headerLabel;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Facing 2 more issues after update the above code
1. Navigation Back Button text not displayed only arrow displayed.
2. I have few more controllers in my project, need to set titleview in all controllers.. 

is possible to update in single line of code change in common ?

Answer (score 1):

Following code to Align the `navigationItem` title. (Only Works from iOS 11 - but the Navigation back and Title y position differs )

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style =  [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
style.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
style.firstLineHeadIndent = 1.0f;
style.lineSpacing = 2; //Change spacing between lines
style.paragraphSpacing = 2; //Change space between paragraphs        

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                                               NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor clearColor],
                                                               NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"FuturaStd-Book" size:18],
                                                               NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style }];
```